# can not use conditions in ggplot with position arguments - conditional dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to set `positon` with some conditions, but an error occured when I use `if_else()`.

A reproducible example is below.

My question is :

How can I use conditions in `position` in ggplot2.

```
library(dplyr)

pd_ture = position_dodge(.4)
pd_false = position_dodge(.6)

mtcars_true = mtcars %>% mutate(test = TRUE)
mtcars_false =mtcars %>% mutate(test = FALSE)


ggplot(mtcars_true, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(position = if_else(unique(mtcars_true$test), pd_ture, pd_false))

# Error in true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))] : 
#  object of type 'environment' is not subsettable

ggplot(mtcars_false, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(position = if_else(unique(mtcars_false$test), pd_false, pd_ture))

# Error in true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))] : 
#  object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

Comment: at least you stayed very consistent with your typo! (pd_ture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do this, but not with `if_else` or `ifelse`, since they will apply the subsetting operator to the output of `position_dodge`, which is not subsettable. Instead, you need a good old-fashioned `if(unique(mtcars_true$test)) pd_ture else pd_false`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars_true, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(position = if(unique(mtcars_true$test)) pd_ture else pd_false)
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering why ifelse threw that error. I am slightly confused (as so often with ifelse vs if... else... ). Why does ifelse apply the subsetting operator to its TRUE and FALSE arguments?

Comment: @tjebo look at the source code for `ifelse`. Effectively, in the last couple of lines, it is trying to call `rep(position_dodge(.4), length.out = 1)[1]`, which fails because of attempting to `rep` an environment. `if_else` fails because its second line is `out <- true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))]`, i.e. it sets up the output vector to be the same class as `true`, and uses subsetting to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.
What you want is a pattern like this:

```r
ggplot(mtcars_true, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(data = . %>% filter(test), position = pd_ture) +
  geom_bar(data = . %>% filter(!test), position = pd_false)
```

But the way you set it up, the `mtcars_true`/`mt_cars_false` is not really made for this. So to make the current setup work, you need:

```r
ggplot(mtcars_true, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(data = mtcars_true, position = pd_ture) +
  geom_bar(data = mtcars_false, position = pd_false)
```

But the pattern of `data = . %>% [data transforming pipes]` will allow you to subset which part of the data the current layer / `geom_*` is being fed.